# app closes during setText

Tags: android, textview, android-checkbox

I have a checkedbox that when, onClick (checked/unchecked), would setText to an activity.

When I run the application, it stopped and will return to the previous page.

What is wrong with my code?

My OrderActivity.java has:

```
public class OrderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
CheckBox OrderMenuBiggDeal, OrderMenuCrispyChicken, OrderMenuExtremeBurger, OrderMenuTenderloinTips;
TextView ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal, ReceiptTextMenuCrispyChicken, ReceiptTextMenuExtremeBurger, ReceiptTextMenuTenderloinTips;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    OrderMenuBiggDeal = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMenu1);
    ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewReceiptMenuPrice1);
```

and

public void onClickBiggDeal(View view){

```
    if(OrderMenuBiggDeal.isChecked()){
        ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal.setText("" + "hello");
    }
    else{
        ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal.setText(R.string.default_value);
    }
```

the application closes on the `ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal.setText("" + "hello");` line.

The setContentView is activity_order.xml.
The location of the TextView that I want to `setText` (ReceiptTextMenuBiggDeal) is on a different xml file, the `activity_receipt.xml`

Comment: change this   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);` to   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);`

Comment: @Haresh i cannot change the setContentView, what I would have want is to send data to another layout so that when I transfer to the next layout, the information will update. Its ok now, i just put the data on the intent.

Comment: So try to get that intent data and base on it update your other layout content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set text on textview that is in other xml, just in one that is set in setcontentview

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);
```

It's because your `TextView` with id `textViewReceiptMenuPrice1` belong to `activity_receipt` layout and you trying to find it on `activity_order` layout.